# slow query with indexed tables Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

I have been working to improve the performance of one of my database(MySQL) Query. The thing is after all that I did, I'm still having slow performance. Before my changes the Query runs at 9.54s and after some index changes the performance improve to 5.67s.

This is my query:

> Query_time: 5.343565  Lock_time: 0.000302  Rows_sent: 100005  Rows_examined: 200017

Code:

```
SET timestamp=1455032448;
SELECT 
     id, 
     description,
     unit_price, 
     (SELECT coalesce(sum(quantity),0) from si_invoice_items where product_id = si_products.id) as qty_out ,
     (SELECT coalesce(sum(quantity),0) from si_inventory where product_id = si_products.id) as qty_in ,
     (SELECT coalesce(reorder_level,0)) as reorder_level ,
     (SELECT qty_in - qty_out ) as quantity,
     (SELECT (CASE  WHEN enabled = 0 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE 'Enabled' END )) AS enabled
FROM 
    si_products  
WHERE 
    visible = 1
    AND domain_id = '1'
ORDER BY 
    description asc;
```

This is the index information of all tables affected:

```
Table Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type   
si_products 0 PRIMARY 1 id A 100005 NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_products 0 PRIMARY 2 domain_id A 100005 NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_products 1 unit_price 1 unit_price A 10000 NULL NULL YESBTREE   
si_products 1 description 1 id A 100005 NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_products 1 description 2 description A 100005 15 NULL  BTREE 

Table  Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type  Comment  Index_comment   
si_inventory 0 PRIMARY 1 domain_id A NULL NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_inventory 0 PRIMARY 2 id A 0 NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_inventory 1 product_id 1 product_id A NULL NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_inventory 1 quantity 1 quantity A NULL NULL NULL  BTREE   

Table  Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type  Comment  Index_comment   
si_invoice_items 0 PRIMARY 1 id A NULL NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_invoice_items 0 PRIMARY 2 invoice_id A 7 NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_invoice_items 1 unit_price 1 unit_price A NULL NULL NULL YES BTREE   
si_invoice_items 1 quantity 1 quantity A NULL NULL NULL  BTREE   
si_invoice_items 1 product_id 1 product_id A NULL NULL NULL YES
```

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

With my last change improve a little bit

> Query_time: 3.723339  Lock_time: 0.000254  Rows_sent: 100005  Rows_examined: 200024 Rows_affected: 0

```
SET timestamp=1455037952;
SELECT  
     A.id, 
     A.description,
     A.unit_price, 
     (SELECT coalesce(sum(B.quantity),0) from si_invoice_items B JOIN si_products A ON B.product_id = A.id) as qty_out ,
     (SELECT coalesce(sum(C.quantity),0) from si_inventory C JOIN si_products A ON C.product_id = A.id) as qty_in ,
     (SELECT coalesce(A.reorder_level,0)) as reorder_level ,
     (SELECT qty_in - qty_out ) as quantity,
     (CASE  WHEN A.enabled = 0 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE 'Enabled' END ) AS enabled
FROM 
    si_products A
WHERE 
    A.visible = 1
    AND A.domain_id = '1'

ORDER BY 
    description asc;
```

Thanks Ollie , I already tried to test the Query with your suggestion but apparently did not improve the response time.

This is the result of your approach:

```
# Query_time: 4.041339  Lock_time: 0.000245  Rows_sent: 100005  Rows_examined: 200029
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1455045101;
SELECT p.id, p.description, p.unit_price,
    COALESCE(invoice.quantity,0) as qty_out,
    COALESCE(inventory.quantity,0)as  qty_in,
    coalesce(p.reorder_level,0) as reorder_level ,
    (select qty_in - qty_out ) as quantity

  FROM si_products p
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity, product_id
                 FROM si_invoice_items 
                GROUP BY product_id
    ) invoice ON p.id = invoice.product_id
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity, product_id
                 FROM si_inventory 
                GROUP BY product_id
    ) inventory ON p.id = inventory.product_id
 WHERE p.visible = 1
   AND p.domain_id = '1'

 ORDER BY            
         description asc;
```

Comment: you're doing correlated subqueries. there's not much you can do to improve things, since each of those queries runs for every row of the parent table that's found. e.g. you're not running one query, you're running n*5 queries, where `n` is the number of records in the parent query.

Comment: Exactly I'm agree with you. The last thing that I did is replace the where clause with  JOIN and improve it to 3.6s.

Comment: If it was me, I'd bin this query and start over with some CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to refactor this query to eliminate the correlated subqueries (the nested SELECTs in your SELECT clause). If you replace those correlated subqueries with JOINed summary subqueries, your performance may improve.

It looks like you need summaries of your `si_invoice_items` and `si_inventory` tables.

You can get those summaries with subqueries like this:

```
               SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity, product_id
                 FROM si_invoice_items 
                GROUP BY product_id
```

and

```
               SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity, product_id
                 FROM si_inventory 
                GROUP BY product_id
```

You can then treat these two subqueries as virtual tables, and JOIN them to your `si_products` table. Notice that you need to use LEFT JOIN because it's possible some of your `si_products` rows won't have matching rows in the other tables.

Like so.

```
SELECT p.id, p.description, p.unit_price,
       COALESCE(invoice.quantity,0) qty_out,
       COALESCE(inventory.quantity,0) qty_in,
       etc, etc
  FROM si_products p
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity, product_id
                 FROM si_invoice_items 
                GROUP BY product_id
       ) invoice ON p.id = invoice.product_id
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity, product_id
                 FROM si_inventory 
                GROUP BY product_id
       ) inventory ON p.id = inventory.product_id
 WHERE p.visible = 1
   AND p.domain_id = '1'
 ORDER BY p.description asc;
```

This will run the summaries on the two tables just once, then join them. So it should run a whole lot faster.

**Edit**  You are fetching more than 100K rows with this query. That's a very large result set and is going to take a while no matter what.

You can make the summary (GROUP BY) subqueries faster by defining compound indexes on the `(product_id, quahtity)` columns on your inventory and invoice tables.

You can make the selection of records from your products table a little faster by defining a compound index on the `(visible, domain_id)` columns.

But your application program still has to grind a hundred thousand rows.

Comment: Thanks Ollie tested the Query with your suggestion but apparently did not improve the response time. Please look at the results. # Query_time: 4.041339  Lock_time: 0.000245  Rows_sent: 100005  Rows_examined: 200029.

Comment: Ollie, I have a suggestion to have your inner pre-aggregate queries ALSO join to the "p" table so you can qualify the visible and domain_id too.  Otherwise, you are summing ALL RECORDS for ALL visible (or not) and domains.  If that is reduced by the qualifying join, you might get better response, especially if those queries are processing 1MIL records from his limited result of 100k for just the domain and visible status.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find better results than this Query:

## Query_time: 3.174778  Lock_time: 0.000250  Rows_sent: 100005  Rows_examined: 200024

## Rows_affected: 0

```
SET timestamp=1455157468;
SELECT  
     A.id, 
     A.description,
     A.unit_price, 
     (SELECT coalesce(sum(B.quantity),0) from si_invoice_items B JOIN si_products A ON B.product_id = A.id) as qty_out ,
     (SELECT coalesce(sum(C.quantity),0) from si_inventory C JOIN si_products A ON C.product_id = A.id) as qty_in ,
     (SELECT coalesce(A.reorder_level,0)) as reorder_level ,
     (SELECT qty_in - qty_out ) as quantity,
     (CASE  WHEN A.enabled = 0 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE 'Enabled' END ) AS enabled
 FROM 
     si_products A
 WHERE 
     A.visible = 1
     AND A.domain_id = '1'

 ORDER BY 
     description asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of how much you are delivering (`Rows_sent: 100005`), the query cannot be very fast.

Either of these indexes would probably help some:

```
INDEX(visible, domain_id, description)
INDEX(domain_id, visible, description)
```

The first 2 fields may help with filtering; the third should prevent needing a "filesort" for the `ORDER BY`.

Do not use a subquery when an expression will suffice.  For example:

```
(SELECT (CASE  WHEN enabled = 0 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE 'Enabled' END )) AS enabled
```

-->

```
IF(enabled, 'Enabled', 'Disabled') AS enabled
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.